login in web page not working like i want
<?php
include 'DataBase+confiq.php';
session_start();
if ($connUsers->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $connUsers->connect_error);
}
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // Prepare the SQL statement to prevent SQL injection
    $stmt = $connUsers->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $login);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        // Verify the password hash
        if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['full_name'] = $row['full_name'];
            header("Location: profile.php");
            exit();  // Make sure to exit after header redirection
        } else {
            echo "<div class='message'>Invalid password.</div>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<div class='message'>No user found with that email.</div>";
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $connUsers->close();
}

?>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
        <div class="field input">
            <label for="login">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="login" name="login" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field input">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </div>
        <div class="links">
            <a href="register.php">Don't have an account? Register here.</a>
        </div>
    </form>

this is my login page php code when i press submit it doesn't do anything, connection with DB is 100% correct, register works fine and inserts the data into the DB! Any solutions?
i tried to rewrite the code and it didnt

How are you sending data to this script?  Please could you share the relevant HTML or JavaScript code?  Have you verified that the right values are indeed being POSTed to the handler, for example using your web browser's developer tools?  Also, do you see anything in the PHP error log?  Answers to these questions might help to resolve your issue

Try doing var_dump($result) and see what it prints

How far through the login process does your code get when you debug it?

object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(5) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }
this appears when I DON'T use the right email and password , the page resets/refreshes when the they are correct even though it should lead to profile with session started

@RobEyre have add it to the post

"doesn't do anything" - that is rarely helpful when talking about code. Do you mean very specifically that an HTTP request is not performed upon clicking the submit button? If so, we can rule PHP out, the problem is client-side then. You haven't posted or talked about JavaScript, so we can rule that out, too. I made a quick demo with your HTML, and after adding an email address and some text into the password field, the submit button does successfully make an HTTP POST.

@ChrisHaas yes its not performed, even though the register works fine

Is there any chance that you have some JavaScript doing anything? Also, any chance you have some CSS such as pointer-events: none on something?

Are you absolutely certain that there is no browser output when your form processing code is running? No blank lines or spaces before the opening PHP tag, for example, and nothing in your include file? That would prevent your header redirect from working, though you should get a "headers already sent" error.

@ChrisHaas javaScript code is working okay and i did check css code is also working fine

@droopsnoot yah i am sure

So, we can completely disregard all PHP then, since we're talking solely about an HTML form making an HTTP request? Once HTML is delivered to a client, the connection to the server is closed and PHP cannot influence it anymore. Would you agree with that? And if you say "JavaScript code is working okay", I'll take your word and we can ignore that, too. If this is truly the case, please update the question and tags, removing everything that is no longer relevant. I think the subject should be "HTML form not performing POST request", too.

Form action issue: Your form is set to post to "login.php", which might just be reloading the page without actually processing anything. Try changing it to this instead:
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

This way, it'll post to the current page, whatever it's named.
Session start placement: You've got session_start() hanging out in the middle of your code. It needs to be at the very top of the file, before any output happens. Otherwise, you might run into header issues.
Debugging: Right now, you can't see what's going on behind the scenes. Let's add some breadcrumbs to follow. Throw this in your code:
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    error_log("Form submitted");
    //code here
}

This will drop a line in your error log when the form is submitted. You can add more of these throughout your code to see how far it's getting.
Form submission check: You're assuming the form fields are always there, but what if they're not? Add a check like this:
if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    //login logic here
} else {
    error_log("not set");
}

This way, you'll know if the form fields are actually being submitted.
Give these changes a shot and see if it helps. If you're still stuck, you might need to dig deeper into your server logs or add more debug statements to figure out where things are going sideways.
